# can't make system tray transparent like rest of the bar in polybar

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, gnome-shell

I am on Pop OS and trying to setup a system tray in my polybar. Here are the relevant parts of my config:

```
[colors]
background = #885e697a

[bar/top]
...
tray-position = right
tray-detached = true
tray-maxsize = 10
tray-offset-x = -50
tray-offset-y = 0
tray-padding = 10
tray-scale = 1.0
tray-transparent = true
tray-background = ${colors.background}
```

and here is the image:
[image]

As you can see, system tray has the same color without transparency applied. I read somewhere that it might be due to compositor and that using for example `compton` did solve the problem, but since I am on GNOME Pop OS I can only use gnome-shell.

I also read somewhere that I should try to apply transparency some other way, using `xrgb` value or something similar, but I am not familiar with that.

Other than that, if I set the color to be the same for system tray and the bar, bar casts a shadow around it and also shows up in full screen while watching youtube video for example.

I am not familiar if this can be solved since polybar is not made with gnome in mind so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Pop Os has its own support: https://support.system76.com/

Comment: @IporSircer I do not believe this is exactly Pop OS related